# The trick for doing Stream

Tags: ocaml

I am currently trying to fully understand **stream**. The concept is not complicated. It is like a list, but the tail part is a `thunk` instead of concrete sub list.

I can write stream like this:

```ml
type 'a stream_t = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream_t)

let hd = function
  | Nil -> failwith "hd"
  | Cons (v, _) -> v

let tl = function
  | Nil -> failwith "tl"
  | Cons (_, g) -> g()

let rec take n = function
  | Nil -> []
  | Cons (_, _)  when n = 0 -> []
  | Cons (hd, g) -> hd::take (n-1) (g())


let rec filter f = function
  | Nil -> Nil
  | Cons (hd, g) ->
    if f hd then Cons (hd, fun() -> filter f (g()))
    else filter f (g())
```

So far so good and I can write a simple stream:

```ml
let rec from i = Cons (i, fun() -> from (i+1))
```

Now, if I was asked to do a **primes** stream, I feel very difficult. I want to use *sieve algorithm*. Without thinking of stream, I can do it easily. But for stream, I can't do.

I searched for the code:

```ml
(* delete multiples of p from a stream *)
let sift p = filter (fun n -> n mod p <> 0)

(* sieve of Eratosthenes *)
let rec sieve = function
  | Nil -> Nil
  | Cons (p, g) -> 
    let next = sift p (g()) in
    Cons (p, fun () -> sieve next)

(* primes *)
let primes = sieve (from 2)
```

I can almost understand that it is working. But where is the trick?

Also how to do a stream of permutation of a list?

Comment: It's hard to answer because there is no trick. The `sieve` function works because the head of the stream is always the next prime. The `filter` function skips over elements that don't pass a test. So in practice the nested filters cause each new int to be tested against all primes seen so far (largest first).

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Will this kind of filter nesting cause stackoverflow?

Comment: When you reach a new prime, it looks to me like there is a nested call to `filter` for each prime seen so far. So yes, the stack will get deeper and deeper until it overflows. There are around `n / ln n` primes less than n, so the depth grows relatively quickly if this is right.

Comment: I ran a test on my MacBook Pro, and the code does indeed cause a stack overflow after producing the prime 7720123. The constant accumulation of `filter`s to call also makes the code pretty slow (quadratic in n), so it took 5 hours to reach this prime.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield thanks for your test. It is slow anyway (large n) or it is because of the stream or functional implementation? I bet it is slow anyway.

Comment: @JacksonTale: I highly recommend that you check out the paper [The Genuine Sieve of Erasthostenes](http://cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) (pdf link), by Melissa O'Neil. She explains why your algorithm has bad asymptotic complexity and also gives a more efficient algorithm thats as efficient as the sieving algorithm you would use on an array.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see where this would cause a stack overflow, all recursive calls are either in tail position or returned in closures. The only non-tail recursive code I can see is in `take`.

Comment: I claim the recursive call happens in `g ()` inside `filter` for this code. In practice there is a stack overflow; I tested.

Comment: @LeoWhite I agree with @jeffreyscofield. in the very begining, g() is the `from`, then g() becomes nested filter.